# Convert .osm to .map for mapsforge

Tags: android, osmosis

I have download latest version of osmosis from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Downloading 
and mapsforge-map-writer-0.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar from 
https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/downloads/list.

I copied  mapsforge-map-writer-0.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar into

1- osmosis lib directory: osmosis-latest/lib/default

2- C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Openstreetmap\Osmosis\Plugins

3- C:\Users\username\AppData\Local.openstreetmap\osmosis\plugins

I downloaded iran.osm file from geofabrik.de and then I created a batch file
as below:

```
osmosis --rx file=iran.osm --mw file=iran.map bbox=35.574683,51.086426,35.833402,51.664581 type=hd
```

and I got this error:

```
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Cannot load JPF-plugin 'org.mapsforge.MapFileWriter' for extensionpoint 'Task' at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.TaskRegistrar.loadJPFPlugins(TaskRegistrar.java:186)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.TaskRegistrar.initialize(TaskRegistrar.java:88)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:81)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.java.plugin.PluginLifecycleException: plug-in org.mapsforge.map.mapfile-writer requires plug-in org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.plugin.Core which is unknown or has incompatible version at org.java.plugin.standard.StandardPluginManager.checkPrerequisites(StandardPluginManager.java:460) at org.java.plugin.standard.StandardPluginManager.activatePlugin(StandardPluginManager.java:397)
    at org.java.plugin.standard.StandardPluginManager.activatePlugin(StandardPluginManager.java:245)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.TaskRegistrar.loadJPFPlugins(TaskRegistrar.java:182)
    ... 12 more
```

PS: I switched back to osmosis 0.36 and I got this error:

```
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-rx failed
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Cannot represent 2147487728 as an integer.
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.util.LongAsInt.longToInt(LongAsInt.java:33)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.domain.v0_6.CommonEntityData.init(CommonEntityData.java:142)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.domain.v0_6.CommonEntityData.<init>(CommonEntityData.java:74)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.domain.v0_6.Entity.<init>(Entity.java:61)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.domain.v0_6.Node.<init>(Node.java:71)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.xml.v0_6.impl.NodeElementProcessor.begin(NodeElementProcessor.java:87)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.xml.v0_6.impl.OsmHandler.startElement(OsmHandler.java:90)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.xml.v0_6.XmlReader.run(XmlReader.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try Osmosis 0.40.1 as this guide shows with mapsforge 0.3.0  https://github.com/cgeo/cgeo/wiki/How-to-create-your-own-offline-maps

Comment: 0.40.1 was the solution!

Answer (score 3):

The plugin has issues with other version of osmosis, other than the osmosis 0.40.1 version. So whoever is using the map writer plugin for mapsforge, it is recommended that they use osmosis version 0.40.1.

Comment: Apart from that, the older version of osmosis can not handle node numbers exceeding the 64-bit-limit which has been hit recently.

Comment: I think osmosis 0.40.1 cannot handle 64 bit limit as well.

Comment: There were some issues in 0.42 as well; but they should be fixed in the current 0.43.1 build.

Comment: I'm using 0.43.1 and I get this exact same error.. strange